# Optimal job scheduling for a medical clinic

Tags: optimization, scheduling, mathematical-optimization, schedule, job-scheduling

I am seeking an optimal solution to the following problem.

I have 3 junior medical officers (MOs) and only 1 consultant. The clinic starts at 0800 HRS; there are 12 patients in total to be seen; and the last patient should ideally start his appointment at 1100 HRS. In addition, all 3 MOs must start seeing 1 patient each at 0800 HRS.

Each patient must be seen in the following order: first by a medical officer (MO), followed by the consultant. A patient may experience a waiting time (T) between being seen by a medical officer, and being seen by the consultant.

The objective is to reduce the average waiting time (T). How then should we schedule the clinic? This problem is also illustrated in the attached Table.

I suspect that this scenario can be treated as a flow shop scheduling problem - all suggested solutions will be greatly appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpiBO.png)

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a form of **Job Shop Scheduling** (so optimality will be hard when scaling out because it's NP-complete/hard). You're basically assigning each job (= 1 appointment of 1 patient) to a machine (= 1 medical officer). On top of that, you have job dependencies (because the 2 appointments of a patient on the same day must be in a certain order).

A typical approach is a Construction Heuristic followed by a Local Search (such as Tabu Search). There's a bunch of solvers out there that can help you solve this with such algorithms. For example in Java, there's [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/) that has 2 examples similar to this: [Project Job Scheduling](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2zweB9JD7c&list=PLJY69IMbAdq0uKPnjtWXZ2x7KE1eWg3ns) and [Nurse Rostering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nPagqJK3bs).

Comment: Dear Geoffrey, my sincere apologies that I am not well-acquainted with scheduling problems. I would be very grateful if you might be able to provide a solution from one of your following software. Please find a copy of our timetable here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MpiBO.png